# getting a win percentage from one-hot encoded dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have this one-hot encoded dataframe
the win column is one if the observations won and 0 otherwise.
how do i get the win percentage for each one of the categories (food,fitness,retail,grocery)?
each observation can be in multiple categories and some ids are duplicated because each id is an experiment where multiple things can be tested.

```
id food    fitness   retail    grocery win
1  1       0         1         1       1
2  1       0         0         0       0
3  0       1         0         0       1
4  1       0         0         1       1
4  1       0         0         1       0
5  1       0         1         0       1
6  0       1         1         0       1
6  0       1         1         0       0
```

expected output

```
category win_percentage
food     .6
fitness  .66
retail   .75
grocery  .66
```

Comment: sorry if it is obvious but how is the win percentage calculated?

Comment: There are 5 food observations and 3 of them won. so food has a 3/5 win percentage

Comment: By my count, there are either 8 or 6 food rows in `food`, depending if you count duplicates or not, and either 5 or 3 of them are marked `1`. So that looks like either `.625` or `.5`. Could you clarify a little more?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
df1 = df.drop(['id','win'], 1)
win_percent = df1[df1 == 1].mul(df.win, 0).mean()
```

**Output**

```
win_percent

food       0.600000
fitness    0.666667
retail     0.750000
grocery    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

---

To get exactly your expected output:

```
win_percent.to_frame('win_percent').rename_axis('category').reset_index()

  category  win_percent
0     food     0.600000
1  fitness     0.666667
2   retail     0.750000
3  grocery     0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

```
category, win_perecentage = [], []
for c in df.loc[:, "food":"grocery"]:
    category.append(c)
    win_perecentage.append(df.loc[df[c] == 1, "win"].sum() / df[c].sum())

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {"category": category, "win_perecentage": win_perecentage}
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  category  win_perecentage
0     food         0.600000
1  fitness         0.666667
2   retail         0.750000
3  grocery         0.666667
```